# Laravel 'WHERE' function in query breaks API?

Tags: php, laravel, api, dhtmlx, gantt-chart

I'm trying to make Gantt's chart using DHTMLX Gantt API.

The goal is to show only certain Gantt's lines to certain users. So for example: if I open a contract it shows me the Gantt's chart of that contract, but if I have permission for ex: purchases, then it should only show me the line with certain *permission ID* which is in the **DB** table **Task**.

Now the problem is somewhere around this function:

```
    public function getOne($id){
      $tasks = new Task();
      $links = new Link();

      return response()->json([
          "data" => $tasks->where('relation_id', $id)->where('permission', 2)->get(),
          "links" => $links->all()
      ]);
    }
```

The *'relation_id'* works fine and shows only a single project, but when I try to add another WHERE it just breaks without errors and doesn't load the chart information.

I think it has to do something with the JSON as if I do just send this query on any other page without inserting into GANTT (just as JSON) it shows me the correct information.

So basically I need to make that query work with this API, I have no clue about why 1 extra line of statement would break it.

I also tried the WHERE statement like this:

```
"data" => $tasks->where([['relation_id', '=', $id],['permission','=',2]])->get()
```

Here is the link to the Gantt chart: [link](https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/)

I followed the steps in their documentation to start: [link](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__howtostart_php_laravel.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi your instantiating an object and trying to access a static method hence, its failing

try this

```
public function getOne($id){
  $tasks = Task::query();
  $links = Link::query();

  return response()->json([
      "data" => $tasks->where('relation_id', $id)->where('permission', 2)->get(),
      "links" => $links->get()
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sadly - same result, no errors in console or anywhere else... But static method does not fail with one statement? Interesting.

Comment: it should. can you just try removing where and see if u have data?

Comment: If I remove the WHERE Permission part - it shows me the chart no problem, but without exclusion. Permission column is 100% there with values of 2.

**EDIT: I think the problem is that theses charts loose their parent row. I will try to figure it out.**

Comment: I was right, it was the parent issue as well. Now I get different hoops to hop, but thank you for you answer. **May the bug lord not cross your paths, kind sir!**

Answer (score 0):

Try using parameter grouping, explained here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#parameter-grouping. So it’ll look something like:

```php
$tasks->where(function($query) {
    $query->where(‘relation_id’, $id)
               ->where(‘permission’, 2);
})->get();
```

You also don’t need to have the “=” as this is understood by Laravel in the where statement if you leave it out (it’s only necessary for the other binary operations).

So I say all of this, but why are you creating a new task and then filtering it with a where statement? You should be getting all of the tasks and filtering them that way. For example:

```php
$tasks = Task::where(...)->get();
$links = Link::get();

return response()->json([‘tasks’ => $tasks, ‘links’ => $links]);
```

This is easier and should give you the result you’re looking for. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, sadly this throws me a internal error 500 in console. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: @Schribs please provide more details. That error sounds like you're attempting to access the "length" property of something that doesn't exist (this shouldn't cause that error because we aren't doing anything with a "length" property). May be an error caused by something that happens after this function.

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating a new task so stop using **new**, you need to go with **query()**

```
$tasks = Task::query();
$links = Link::query();

$tasks->where(['relation_id' => $id, 'permission' => 2])->get();
```